# Is it possible to represent as a smooth curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Consider a curve $\gamma(t) = (x_{1}(t),x_{2}(t))$, such as : [image]

Suppose angle between parts of the curve is $\alpha \ne \pi/2$. Is it possible to represent it like a smooth curve $(x_{1}(t),x_{2}(t))$,where $x_{i}(t) \in C^{\infty}$?

I know that it's possible for $\alpha = \pi/2$, but what about this curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. Just let the speed of the curve slow down in a smooth fashion to $0$ when approaching the corner (use something which behaves like $\exp(-1/x^2)$ near $x=0$).

But not as a regular curve, i.e. a curve with nonvanishing derivative.

Comment: Wouldn't it then take infinite time just to reach the vertex and so the curve will not be completed?

Comment: Yes, I should agree with @wilkersmon , I guess we should decrease speed of the curve infinite time.

Comment: @wilkersmon you are mixing up the dynamics of the curve with the geometry. And yes, it will take infinitely long.

Comment: So the way I see it, then the curve you're describing wouldn't  satisfy your the requirements as the image of the real line in that curve would only be one part of the curve, so it wouldn't be the curve that the asker was looking for...

Comment: @Thomas actually I'm interested in finding such functions , as it possible , or constructing them

Comment: @openspace As indicated in my answer, try $exp(-1/x^2)$ near $ x= 0$. This will work for both positive and negative $x$. Start out with a parametriziation by arclength such that $t=0$ maps to the vertex. This parametrization will have a disconuity for the derivative at $x=0$ Then reparametrize with $exp(-1/x^2)$.

Comment: @Thomas, i guess we could use $x_{t} = e^{-1/x^2}$ near $x = 0$ to get a right angle

Comment: Maybe it better to consider $(x_{1}(e^{-1/t^{2}}), x_{2}(t))$

Comment: @openspace yes, $\exp(-1/x^2) $ is what I have suggested several times by now. The details I will leave to you.

Comment: @Thomas the last question , so if i represent it like $(x_{1}(\exp(-\beta / t^{2}), x_{2}(t))$ , then it will be an appropriate answer?

Comment: @openspace that depends on how $x_2(t)$ is defined. It has to slow down to speed zero like $x_1$, since otherwise it will not be differentiable at $t=0$. If you don't know whether the parametrization satisfies your needs you should investigate. Write it down explicitly and calculate it's tangent vector to see whether it is smooth.

Comment: @Thomas you mean tangent vector at $t = 0$?

Comment: @openspace in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: @Thomas yes. So I should find tangent vector to $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ , then consider angle between them and find relationships between $x_{2}$ and $x_{1}$?

Comment: @Thomas something like that is good : $x_{1}(t) = e^{-1/t^2}, t \ne 0$, $x_{2}(t) = \cot(\alpha) e^{-1/t^{2}}, t < 0$ and $x_{2}(t) = 0 , t \ge 0$?

Comment: @openspace yes, apart from the fact that it should be $\tan(\alpha)$ -- I'd assume $\alpha$ is the angle between the positve $x_1$ axis and the upper part of the curve?

Comment: @Thomas yes , that should be $\tan(\alpha)$